# Do the Borg feel pain?

Tags: star-trek, borg

I'm re-watching *ST: First Contact* and just saw the scene where they're attaching an ocular device to an implant on a newly assimilated Borg. The former Enterprise crewmember was just lying there while the procedure was being performed--no screaming or obvious flinching.

The Borg Queen obviously understands pain and pleasure, as evidenced by her treatment of Data. But do the Borg actually feel physical pain during/after assimilation?

Comment: Pain is irrelevant.

Comment: Except that I could see drones being all "Why is this drone-to-be flailing around during the assimilation process? It is causing damage to its organic components." And eventually concluding that blocking pain receptors would be a logical step in the assimilation process.

Comment: Perhaps it's fair to say that **your pain** is irrelevant to the Collective.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**

> **SEVEN:** *Do you think I'm disgusting?*
>
> **IKO:** *You've been nothing but kind to me.*
>
> **SEVEN:** *You asked me earlier if it hurt when my occipital implant was installed. I told you I didn't remember. But the truth is, it was **one of the most painful experiences of my life.***
>
> **IKO:** *Why did you lie?*
>
> **SEVEN:** *It's difficult for me to talk about, because I forced others to undergo the same procedure.*
>
> **IKO:** *Why?*
>
> **SEVEN:** *I was compelled to do so by the Borg Collective. I wasn't in control of my actions, just as you weren't in control when you took
> a life. My nanoprobes have given you control. You're a different
> person now. You don't deserve to be executed.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Voy: Repentance](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Repentance_(episode))</sup></sub>

As for the Borg *after* assimilation, I'd say again yes. The Borg wouldn't care if a Drone is in pain as long as it does its job (no local anesthetics here)

---

**EDIT** as for them not 'flailing around', remember they don't have control after the nano-probes are injected. Think being operated on while you're paralysised but still awake (Picard managed to shed a tear in TNG:Best-Of-Both-worlds. Drones is a good word, the Borg don't care as long as the Drone functions

Comment: The question asked for during and after assimilation, and it stands to reason if they don't care during, they wouldn't care after. I can't find any reference to after either way in regards to pain. They think people would 'want' to be borg too, so some painkillers would be given if they cared.  Only reference close is when 7 says the Borg wouldn't care if drone remembered being individuals VOY:Instinct. If pain was an issue then it would help them get 'followers' watching peaceful assimilation's not horrifyingly painful ones. And thanks for the edit (That's what I was trying to do)

Comment: That's fair. I was mostly looking at the title rather than the specific wording. You have my +1 for addressing the bit *before* full assimilation.